# Automapper common map part

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-6

I.e. I have the following map class:

```
public class AutoMapperAddress : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperAddress()
    {
        CreateMap<AddressDto, ViewModels.AddressElementAPI>();
    }
}
```

then I should use it in other places, i.e:

```
public class AutoMapperLocation : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperLocation()
    {
        // location mappers here
        // I need the same Address mapping as AutoMapperAddress has
    }
}

public class AutoMapperCarrier : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperCarrier ()
    {
        // carrier mappers here
        // I need the same Address mapping as AutoMapperAddress has
    }
}
```

How to do it?

**ADDED:**

I tried to solve it during create mapper object:

```
        mapper = (new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<Models.AutoMapperRules.AutoMapperLocation>();
            cfg.AddProfile<Models.AutoMapperRules.AutoMapperAddress>();
            }
        )).CreateMapper();
```

but I want to incapsulate it inside AutoMapperLocation, because no sense to have AutoMapperLocation without AutoMapperAddress

Comment: Implement AutoMapperAddress from the other claases and make the address public? Or put the Address in the constructor?

Comment: could you show an example?

Comment: At map time, all the maps are available, no matter what profile they are defined in.